# Mercurial can't find username config on Cygwin

Tags: version-control, windows-7, mercurial, cygwin

I am getting the `abort: no username supplied (see "hg help config")` error when trying to use `hg commit` on Cygwin. I have setup the Mercurial.ini file properly in my /users/username directory (I am on Windows 7).

Using `hg showconfig --debug` returns the following:

```
read config from: /usr/etc/mercurial/hgrc
read config from: /etc/mercurial/hgrc
read config from: /home/Mark/.hgrc
```

Thus I am assuming since I'm using Cygwin, it's checking for the Mercurial config files as though I was using Linux. Has anyone else encountered this problem using Mercurial with Cygwin?

How can I get Mercurial to check in the right folders for the config files (again for using Cygwin on Windows 7)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a workaround, you could just set the HGUSER environment variable to your desired user name.

But a better solution would be to add a `%include` line to one of the hgrc files that Hg is reading, to force it to include the one you created - something like:

```
%include /users/username/.hgrc
```

You might even be able to get Cygwin to use $USER or similar, to avoid a hard-coded username.

See [the hgrc man page](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgrc.5.html) for more info.

Comment: None of the directories shown actually exist on my system, so Mercurial isn't currently reading any hgrc files.

Comment: Ah right. Have you tried creating one of these directories for Cygwin anyway, and crating the file in it?